# What actions do not refelect in the user activity list?

Tags: bug, recent-activity

Recently, I have voted to reopen this question: [Since yesterday, I can not access mercadolibre.com.ar anymore](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/since-yesterday-i-can-not-access-mercadolibre-com-ar-anymore#)
but it does not show in my activity list. I have requested this on the question page instead of from review page. It seems to me that it maybe a bug? Is it a bug? Other than that, what type of activity do not show on the user activity list?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your [activity list](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/923/roya?tab=activity) in your parent profile, it's broken down pretty well. Votes, for the most part, don't make a lot of noise there.

Sure, if you down-vote something, folks will see a small reputation change in your reputation history. But they don't see this if you up vote, vote to close, vote to delete, or vote to re-open a post. That's a little *too* much of a ticker tape about how you use the site, and I think quite a few would be a bit uncomfortable if other users had the ability to track your *every* move.

*Everything* you do on the site will affect the 'last seen' portion of your profile, letting folks know if you're still around (useful if someone leaves a comment for you and wonders if they should stick around another 20 minutes or head outside). While who voted to close / delete / re-open something isn't *private* information, you need to be on the particular post where the vote was cast in order to see it.